# Problema al pasar URL en función $.ajax de JQuery usando Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Estoy usando codeigniter pero al llamar una función de mi controlador desde Ajax en JQuery me envía el siguiente error

> http://127.0.0.1:8080/project/Grupo/Edit/%3C?php%20echo%20base_url();%20?%3EGrupo/obtieneMat

No me respeta el enlace que quiero llamar para la función.

Este es mi código:

```
$.ajax({
      data:  datos,
      url:   "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Grupo/obtieneMat",
      type:  'post',
      beforeSend: function () {
           $("#MateriaSelect").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
      },
           success:  function (html) {
           $("#MateriaSelect").html(html);
           var IdMateria = $('#MateriaSelect').val();
           obtieneHoras(IdMateria);
      }
        });
```

Comment: Se mas especifico, lo del error no esta bien explicado y no sabemos como esta compuesta la función de tu controlador para saber el porque del error.

Comment: ¿`<?php echo base_url(); ?>` te imprime una diagonal al final?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar realizarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$.ajax({
    data: datos,
    url: "<?php echo base_url('Grupo/obtieneMat'); ?>",
    type: 'post',
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#MateriaSelect").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
    },
    success: function(html) {
        $("#MateriaSelect").html(html);
        var IdMateria = $('#MateriaSelect').val();
        obtieneHoras(IdMateria);
    }
});
```

Te debería de funcionar sin problemas.

Answer (score -1):

Nunca uses php dentro de javascript,
mejor crea un input hidden con el valor de base_url
y luego con jquery obtienes el valor de ese input hidden y lo pasas como parametro del string url.

```
<input type="hidden" id="base_url" value="<?=base_url();?>">

var base_url = $(input#base_url").val();
$.ajax({
  data:  datos,
  url:   "base_url/Grupo/obtieneMat",
  type:  'post',
  beforeSend: function () {
       $("#MateriaSelect").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
  },
       success:  function (html) {
       $("#MateriaSelect").html(html);
       var IdMateria = $('#MateriaSelect').val();
       obtieneHoras(IdMateria);
  }
    });
```